# Set my locale in iphone

Tags: iphone, locale

I am doing an application which user count down timer. The timer works fine with my simulator. but when i install it in to my device the timer is showing some time difference. Hope its the problem with locale. Can any one provide me some help to fix this problem.?? Please...

Thanks in Advance,
Shibin

Comment: You should add more information and description. Some time difference is a very common phrase. It can be almost anything.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, it's hard to answer your question, but almost surely the [Date and Time Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/) will be able to help you.